# UploadFile C# alternative in PHP

Tags: c#, php, curl

I have been given this code example in C#

```
var fileUploadClient = new WebClient();
fileUploadClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
var rawResponse = fileUploadClient.UploadFile(Url, FilePath);
```

I'm trying to replicate this in PHP with:

```
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.dev/import");
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/xml',
        'Authorization: api '.$this->token
    ));
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => new \CurlFile('/tmp/import.xml', 'application/xml', 'import.xml')));

     $response = curl_exec($handle);
     $code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

However it seems like this is not identical to the C# example because I'm getting an internal server error message. Anybody know the differences?

Comment: directory permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

;8Try to upload the file directly into the `POSTFIELDS`

```
## also remember to use full path
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents('/home/dir/import.xml'));
```

Also, make sure you have permission to access the xml file.

Comment: No difference, I'm still getting the same error. I have access to the file, permission is not the problem.

Comment: This seems to be the function they are using in the example. It just says that i POST the file to the server. Anybody know the difference between that and what I'm doing here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144229.aspx